# Error al mostrar items de Arraylist en android

Tags: android, android-studio, listview

Estoy enviando a traves de un intent un arraylist, éste se va llenando conforme van llegando nuevos mensajes y los muestro en una notificación, al ser clickeada dicha notificación se debe mostrar en una nueva vista todos los items Este es mi codigo:

```
private Emitter.Listener recibir_mensajes = new Emitter.Listener(){
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
            try {
                id_modal = 2;
                a = data.getString("a");
                b = data.getString("b");
                c = data.getString("c");
                datos_mensajes_estudiante = new Datos_mensajes_estudiante(a,b,c);
                arrayList.add(datos_mensajes_estudiante);
                Log.d("PPPPPP",""+arrayList.size());
                if(!MapsActivity.validar_not_MapsActivity && !Todos_mensajes.validar_not_Todos_mensajes){
                    mostrar_notificacion();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // return;
            }
        }
    };


private void mostrar_notificacion(){
        Intent notificacion = new Intent(this,Todos_mensajes.class);
        notificacion.putExtra("id_modal",id_modal);
        notificacion.putParcelableArrayListExtra( "arraylist", arrayList);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificacion,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri ringtone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        Builder builder = new Builder(this);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setContentTitle("Alerta");
        builder.setContentText("sms nuevo");
        builder.setSound(ringtone);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.icono);
        builder.setTicker("Nuevo mensaje ");
        builder.setLights(Color.GREEN, 1, 1);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,builder.build());
    }
```

Esto al recibir en mi vista Todos_mensajes solo me muestra el ultimo item y no todos pero si lleno el arraylist de la siguiente manera:

```
arrayList.add(new Datos_mensajes_estudiante("a","B","C"));
                arrayList.add(new Datos_mensajes_estudiante("a","B","C"));
                arrayList.add(new Datos_mensajes_estudiante("a","B","C"));
                arrayList.add(new Datos_mensajes_estudiante("a","B","C"));
```

si llegan todos los items.

¿cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: la verdad esque lo que tengo esta bien hasta imprimo el tamaño de mi arraylist pero cuando doy click en mi notificacion alli solo se muestra 1 solo item no todos

Comment: Amigo ya lo pude solucionar tan solo debi cambiarFLAG_ONE_SHOT  por esto FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT y listo

Comment: Muy bien, me alegro.